# Unresolvable problem

Tags: security

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while initialising the package information.

Please report this bug for the 'update-manager' package and try to include the following error message:

'E:Malformed line 57 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)'
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. When asking questions, you need to also tell us what you were doing. It looks like this is the error you got when attempting to do something, what was it you were doing? It is also considered nice to actually _ask_ something and not just dump the error message.

Comment: You could upload your sources.list file to pastebin.org and copy the link to your post ([edit] it), so that we can check what's wrong and tell you how to repair it. leave me a comment (@ByteCommander), when you did that.

Answer (score -1):

Count down to Line 57 of the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and just delete it from the file.

In order to modify the file, remember you'll need to open it as root with the following command:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

After bringing this file back to normal, run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Just blindly deleting things is _not_ the way to go...